# Get element offset relative to document without getBoundingClientRect (Webkit bug)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cross-browser, webkit

Positioning a tooltip / popup is usually simply a case of using **getBoundingClientRect()** or jQuery's **offset()** function (which internally uses getBoundingClientRect) to get the offset relative to the document or window, but if you zoom in on some Webkit browsers, these functions start returning unexpected / wrong results because the getBoundingClientRect function is implemented weirdly in Webkit. This has been an issue forever and for some reason has never been fixed.

Question: How can I (if even possible) calculate the exact pixel offset of an element relative to the document **without using getBoundingClientRect()** so that the values **don't** change on zoom?

Comment: Can you clarify a few things here? You say "some webkit browsers" do you have specific ones where this is a problem e.g.  does it happen in Chrome or only in Opera? Does zoom refer to pinch zooming on a mobile device, the browser zoom (^+/^- or ⌘+/⌘-) on desktop, or CSS scaling? For instance, I tested in Chrome (Canary) by making a clickable div and have it log its getBoundingClientRect and checked the values after changing the browser zoom level and apart from one or two subpixel positioning quirks, I did not see the values changing.

Comment: I'm not sure on the exact versions. What I do know is that it happens on my phone. Using the latest mobile Chrome. And I'm indeed talking about pinch zoom. Sorry for the confusion. So jQuery's offset().left for example changes when you are zooming in (pinch). And the closer to the left edge of the screen you 'pinch', the greater the offset().left value.

Comment: Are you able to put a reduced example case together? I'm not seeing this happening for me locally, so if you would be able to either update your answer with the minimum HTML/CSS/JS required to reproduce (or make a JSFiddle/JSBin) that would go a long way toward someone being able to help you figure out what's happening :)

Comment: Sure. https://output.jsbin.com/setogicota Open on Chrome on Android, and pinch to zoom. The tooltip should stick to the bottom-right of the input, but it doesn't. On Chrome (I'm on Linux), if I zoom in it works as expected. If I now subtract the scrollX from the left position, and the scrollY from the top position, it works. But then it's buggered up on desktop Chrome. It seems that changing to getBoundingClientRect reverses the effect.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this in https://jsbin.com/vaculorita/1/edit?css,js,output

I'm not sure what jQuery's offset is trying to do but the combination of switching to absolute positioning and manually using getBoundingClientRect works for me.

HTML

```
<div id="tooltip">Tooltip</div>
<input type="text" id="username">
```

CSS

```
#username {
  margin-left: 54px;
  margin-top: 21px;
}

#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top:0;
}
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  function moveTooltip() {
    var $tooltip = $('#tooltip').first();
    var $input = $('#username').first();
    var rect = $input.get(0).getBoundingClientRect();
    $tooltip.css('left', rect.left + $input.width());
    $tooltip.css('top', rect.top + $input.height());

  }

  moveTooltip();

  $(window).on('resize scroll', moveTooltip);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work correctly. If the width of the page is higher than the windows width, you get the same result. Check this bin: https://jsbin.com/pozujezufi/1/edit?html,css,js,output. Scroll to the right in the output, and you see the offset is wrong again. Only thing I changed is I set the body to 3000px width and height.

Comment: Sure that's a fair point, if you delete the event handler and just position the element and don't worry about trying to move it when the browser scrolls/resizes/zooms it should just work (I think initially you might have had problems because your tooltip was `position: fixed` rather than `absolute`. See https://jsbin.com/lalumi/2/edit?js for a working example.

Comment: Problem is that my entire goal is to dynamically move elements to other elements. So I want to position a popup to the right of an element on click / focus / whatever. It has to be on-the-fly and dynamic.

Comment: You can still do that, you would need to get the element you want to move to from the event handler, then you could move another element to the corresponding position of that element. There are a few different approaches to implementing something like that, but that's probably beyond the scope of this question/answer.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think we are on the same path here. The entire problem I'm facing is that if I pinch-zoom on my application and I focus on the input my tooltip goes to the wrong location, because I can't get an accurate offset position. The goal of the question has been a fix to this bin: https://jsbin.com/pozujezufi/1/edit?html,css,js,output. Currently this bin doesn't work properly on desktop, while on my phone it's working.

Comment: @Basaa like I said before, if you remove the resize/scroll event handler ([like in this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/cacimoq/1/edit?css,js,output)) to move the popup when the page is scrolled then this should work as far as I can tell. If it is not working in your actual environment for some reason you'll need to put together a better example that shows the problem more accurately.

Comment: I see what you mean. Problem is as follows: I have to show and move the tooltip while the window is zoomed in. Example: If you focus on an input on mobile that is too small, the browser will automatically zoom in on it. Then if you focus on the next input, I'm unable to calculate the new position. So the tooltip has to move around from element to element  *while zoomed in*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127673/discussion-between-dymos-and-basaa).